# HP printer is printing only English part not Hindi one

Tags: firefox, printing, language-support

I don't know why my printer is only printing English part of paper, It leaves blank Hindi part. Anyone have faced this problem?

And When I opened the document in ***Firefox***, it was not displaying Hindi part in proper way. But it worked in ***Chrome***.

I am using **ubuntu 14.04**.

Printer **HP Laser Jet Professional m 1136 MFP printer**

Using **hp-setup** too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Resolved this problem by installing Hindi fonts #selfNote